# Adding scroll feature to the form

Tags: javascript, html, css

The problem here I face is that my form remains static on the window.But what I want is that the `form_1` should jump to the top of the window as the user writes his query in the "**Enter your starting**" city text box.

```
<html>
<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style type="text/css">
    img.bg {
        min-height: 100%;
        min-width: 1024px;

        width: 100%;
        height: auto;

        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 1024px){
        img.bg {
            left: 50%;
            margin-left: -512px; }
        #form_1 {
            width: 20%;
        }
    }

    #form_1 {     
        position: relative;
        border-radius: 15px;

        width: 80%;
        margin: 15% auto; 
        padding: 20px;
        background: white;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 20px black;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px black; 
        box-shadow: 0 0 20px black;
        display: table;
        border :solid 2px  black;
        padding: 15px;
    }

    .row {
        display:table-row;
    }

    .row label {
        text-align: right;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="yt" >
    <img src="bg.jpg" class="bg">
    <form id="form_1" tabindex="0">
    <label>Enter Starting City</label>
    <div class="row">
    <input type="text" name="s_city"></br>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <label>Wait While The Cities Appear
    </label></br>
    <textarea rows="10" cols="30"></textarea></br>
    <div class="row">
</form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i have tried using tabindex property and window.location.hash to accomplish it @cale_b

Comment: when entering a query in text area the form jumps to the top of the window but not in the case ,when we enter the query in the "enter your starting city" input type @Eric Müller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed some wrong tag and wrong close tags, Fix those, see if this works.

```html
<html>
  <head>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style type="text/css">
      img.bg {
        min-height: 100%;
        min-width: 1024px;

        width: 100%;
        height: auto;

        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
      }

      @media screen and (max-width: 1024px){
        img.bg {
          left: 50%;
          margin-left: -512px; }
        #form_1 {
          width: 20%;
        }
      }

      #form_1 {     
        position: relative;
        border-radius: 15px;

        width: 80%;
        margin: 15% auto; 
        padding: 20px;
        background: white;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 20px black;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px black; 
        box-shadow: 0 0 20px black;
        display: table;
        border :solid 2px  black;
        padding: 15px;
      }

      .row {
        display:table-row;
      }

      .row label {
        text-align: right;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="yt" >
      <img src="bg.jpg" class="bg" />
      <form id="form_1" tabindex="0">
        <label>Enter Starting City</label>
        <div class="row">
          <input type="text" name="s_city"><br/>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <label>Wait While The Cities Appear</label><br/>
          <textarea rows="10" cols="30"></textarea><br/>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```